# Problems with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a gem I would like to make.  It is suppose to make it easier to make a dynamic form in a controller by allowing you to do this:

```
@actionMenuItems = ActionMenuItem.new("Link Name", url_path)
```

and I have this in my gem in lib/dynamic_form.rb:

```
 module dynamicMenu

 class ActionMenuItem
   attr_accessor :name, :link

   def initialize(name, link)
     @name = name
     @link = link
  end

 end

end
```

However when I try to add this gem into my application I get:

> > uninitialized constant UsersController::ActionMenuItem

this is the first gem I have ever made so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with namespacing. The `ActionMenuItem` is contained within `dynamicMenu` module, so the proper way to refer to it would be `dynamicMenu::ActionMenuItem`.

Comment: I changed it to DynamicMenu and in my controller I did `DynamicMenu::ActionMenu.new("New User", new_user_path)` and I get: `uninitialized constant UsersController::DynamicMenu`

Comment: Have you included the gem in your Rails project or manually required the lib/dynamic_form.rb file?

Comment: Also, class and module names should start with uppercase letters and are case-sensitive. I see you used dynamicMenu in your original post, while here you are using DynamicMenu. Also, should ActionMenu be ActionMenuItem?

Comment: I have added `gem 'dynamic_menu', :git=>"git://github.com/plowdawg/dynamic_menu.git"` to my Gemfile but it gives the error above.

Comment: Also, may I suggest trying out DynamicMenu::ActionMenuItem.new in the Rails console until it works. If it works, then you'll know it's properly referenced through a Gemfile or explicitly by a require.

Comment: Have you ran bundle install after including it?

Comment: You have named the file in your gem wrongly: dynamic_menu / lib / dyanmicMenu.rb... it should be dynamic_menu / lib / dynamic_menu.rb

Comment: I have fixed this and now it looks like the gem is loading, I am working on this error now: `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Alright, found that problem out and it is working...thanks for your help